# Microprofile Config using dynamic config-keys

Tags: jakarta-ee, config, microprofile

I am currently looking for a way to dynamically assemble config-keys (fallback-handling) and then look for those in our microprofile-config.properties files. Such a file might look like this:

```
# customer fallbacks

my.config=1234                            # use this fallback when there is no customer
customer2.my.config=12345                 # use this fallback when there is no subcustomer
customer2.subCustomer1.my.config=123456   # first level
```

So when there is a customer and a subcustomer, then use the on

The reason why i got this problem is that i would like to use the `@ConfigProperty` annotation, so no ConfigProvider.getConfig(). That means that i will have to assemble my dynamic config key inside my custom `ConfigSource`.

I know that ConfigSources are loaded on Server Startup via ServiceLoader. So i tried to remove the existing Configuration and replace it with my custom configuration:

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;

import org.eclipse.microprofile.config.Config;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.config.spi.ConfigProviderResolver;

@Startup
@Singleton
public class StartupConfigurationRegistrar{

@PostConstruct
private void registerConfig() {
        final Config customConfig = ConfigProviderResolver.instance().getBuilder().withSources(new FallbackHandlingConfiguration(myReqiredVariables)).addDefaultSources().build();
        ConfigProviderResolver.instance().releaseConfig(ConfigProviderResolver.instance().getConfig());
        ConfigProviderResolver.instance().registerConfig(customConfig, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
    }
}
```

My ConfigSource is added properly. But later on when a try to access the configuration in a different class, my custom `ConfigSource` has disappeared and only the three default ConfigSources are left. I think this might be a ClassLoader problem.

Any ideas how to get dynamic values inside a `ConfigSource`?

Answer (score 0):

You have a slight misconception of the `ConfigBuilder`. If you use this to create a `Config`then you have to pass it around manually.

But most of the time you usually use our 'auto-discovery' mode. This works with a standard `java.util.ServiceLoader` mechanism. It is described in the spec PDF as well as in the JavaDocs: https://github.com/eclipse/microprofile-config/blob/master/api/src/main/java/org/eclipse/microprofile/config/spi/ConfigSource.java#L64

But I'd rather not have a ConfigSource with dynamic values because that might cause troubles under highly concurrent load.
You might rather take a look at the `addLookupSuffix` mechanism we proposed for ConfigJSR and are right now porting back to mp-config:
https://github.com/eclipse/ConfigJSR/blob/master/api/src/main/java/javax/config/ConfigAccessor.java#L191

It is similar to your initial thoughts, but the .customer2 would be a suffix to the config key. hth.